# How do I know if a specific cisco router and IOS support a certain feature?

Tags: authentication, ios, cisco

The reason I'm asking is I'm trying to set up a Cisco Catalyst 2800 series router as an 802.1x supplicant.  According to this document, http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/sec_usr_8021x/configuration/12-4/sec-user-8021x-12-4-book/sec-vpn-ac-802-1x.html, this feature has been supported since ios 12.4(6)T.  I have ios 12.6(23)b, but when it try to enter the command "aaa authentication dot1x" i only get as far as being able to enter "aaa ?" The only option I have of entering after aaa is "new-model".  Is this feature just not supported on this model router?

Comment: This is a question for Cisco support.

Comment: If I had an account with Cisco support I'd certainly ask them.  However I don't.

Comment: The problem is that this isn't an InfoSec question but a Cisco configuration question.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the device supports it, Cisco by default uses what I call "compatibility mode" for AAA, where it limits the feature set to the "old model".

Use the aaa new-model, then try again.

Comment: The aaa new-model command is even mentioned in the link he provided under the 'Enabling 802.1X Authentication' section...

Answer (score 1):

Try the Cisco feature navigator tool:
http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/CFN/jsp/index.jsp